# Overloading ostream operator to print matrix from file

Tags: c++, file, matrix, operator-overloading

I have matrix class, and two constructors- one which have arguments (rows,cols,number), for example matrix c(4,4,4) will create 4x4 matrix and fill it with number 4.

Second constructor is reading matrix from txt file, and if I print it in constructor everything works fine, but I wanted to overload ostream << operator to print matrix in main function. This operator works for first constructor but doesn't work for the second one, it prints random numbers in infinity loop.

Here's my code, thanks for any advice and help.

```
ostream & operator <<(ostream &o, const matrix &m)
{
  for(int r=0; r<m.rows;r++)
  {
    for(int c=0; c<m.cols;c++)
    {
        o<<m.mat[r][c]<<" ";
    }

   o<<endl;
  }

  return o;
}



matrix::matrix(const char* file_name)
{
  int rows=0;
  int cols=0;
  FILE *fp;
  fp=fopen(file_name,"rb");
  fseek(fp,0,SEEK_SET);
  fscanf(fp,"%d",&rows);
  fscanf(fp,"%d",&cols);

  mat=new double*[rows];

  for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
  {
     mat[i]=new double[cols];
  }

  for(int k=0;k<rows;k++)
  {
    for(int j=0;j<cols;j++)
    {
        fscanf(fp,"%lf",&mat[k][j]);
        //cout<<mat[k][j]; it works.
    }
    cout<<endl;
  }
}
```

EDIT: added first constructor:

```
matrix::matrix(int r, int c, double n)
{
  rows=r;
  cols=c;
  mat= new double*[rows];
  for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
  { 
    mat[i]=new double[cols];}

  for(int k=0;k<rows;k++)
  {
    for(int j=0;j<cols;j++)
    {
        mat[k][j]=n;}
  }
}
```

Comment: _works for first constructor but doesn't work for the second one_. I only see one constructor.

Comment: Oh really sorry, I added him

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your "not-working" constructor has an error indeed. That's because you have defined `rows` and `cols` as local variables, so the `members rows and cols` of the matrix object are not set.

Try removing those local definitions, so that the rows and cols referenced are actually your object's data members. Remove the lines:

> ```
> int rows=0;
> int cols=0;
> ```

Or replace them with:

```
rows = cols = 0;
```